# Prove that two matrices in $SO(3)$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same trace

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

The matrix $SO(3)$ is the group of all $3\times 3$ matrices with determinant=+1. I showed that if the trace is equal then they are conjugate but don't know how to show conjugacy implies equivalent trace.

Comment: Conjugate implies same eigenvalues. Trace is the sum of eigenvalues.

Comment: Your definition of $SO(3)$ is wrong. It is the group of $3 \times 3$ **orthonormal** matrices with determinant $+1$.